# Azure private VMs access using Automation runbooks

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I have created virtual network and VMs with only private ips inside virtual network.I have created an Automation Account and powershell runbooks inside this automation account.

**My goal is to access these VMs using Azure Automation Account Runbooks, but I am not sure how can I do this.**

I have read about Azure private endpoint, and created a private endpoint where private link resources is my automation account.
I can see one network interface is created with a private IP from my virtual network but this also I am not able to figure out how to use for access my VMs using runbooks.

What can I do to access my Azure private VMs using runbooks?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [Hybrid Runbook Workers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker).

Private Endpoints enable private *inbound* connections to the Automation Account, however your aim is to go the other direction and enable runbooks from the automation account to connect to VMs inside your VNET.

Using Hybrid Runbook Workers you basically link a VM to your automation account and the runbook is then executed on that VM (the worker). This way you should be able to access internal resources.